# How to make a search bar that shows whatever the user types in for API data?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning how to work with API's (fetch specifically) and I fetched all the data onto the screen. Now I am trying to figure out how to implement a search bar but I can't figure it out. Would it be easier to use a framework like React? I will take all feedback, I am here to learn.

```js
let elements = document.querySelector(".elements");
let dataaa = document.querySelector(".dataaa");
let searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
// SEARCH FILTER

searchbar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  // HELP HERE
  console.log(e.target.value)
});

function getdata() {
  fetch(
      `https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets?fields=id,slug,symbol,metrics/market_data/price_usd`
    )
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const html = data.data
        .map((pieceofdata) => {
          const name = pieceofdata.slug;
          const symbol = pieceofdata.symbol;
          const price = +pieceofdata.metrics.market_data.price_usd.toFixed(2);
          return `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> ${symbol}</h1><h1 class= "name"> ${name}</h1><h1 class= "price"> $${price}</h1>
                </div>`;
        })
        .join(" ");
      dataaa.innerHTML = html;
      // console.log(data)
      // console.log(html)
    });
}

getdata();
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

#searchbar {
  margin-left: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  outline: none;
  border: white solid 1px;
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

 ::placeholder {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dataaa {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pieceofdata {
  width: 100vw;
  border: 2px rgb(0, 255, 136) solid;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.subtitles {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 136);
}

.symbol {
  color: lime;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.name {
  justify-self: normal;
}

.price {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title">Crytpo Currencies</h1>
  </div>
  <form action=""><input placeholder="Search for Crypto" type="text" name="searchbar" id="searchbar"></form>
  <ul class="subtitles">
    <li class="symbol-title">Symbol</li>
    <li class="name-title">Name</li>
    <li class="price-title">Price</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dataaa">
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to search? Within the data returned from your fetch statement?  Look at the API you're using and see if they have a search parameter

Comment: your code seems ok to me. what is your problem?
also yes something like **React** or **Vue** could help but you should be able to do it in vanilla js

Comment: @SoroushOwji So if the user were to type in "bitcoin" or "bit", I want it to display bitcoin on the screen.

Comment: Let see if I got this right, you have the data, you just want to filter items through it, according to what user types.

Comment: @SoroushOwji correct

Comment: Please do **not** vandalize your posts (rolled back).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to create a filter with vanilla js. (as you said yourself it might be easier to do so with the help of **React** or **Vue**)

but what you can do here is to store your data in an array say like `responseData` in the global script. and also another one for your filtered data. say `filteredData`.

then after each time the user types in a letter and your `eventListener` is called:

```js
  var reg = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'g');
  filteredData = responseData.filter(item => item.{{name}}.match(reg))
```

in `{{name}}` you should put what you are actually looking for.
and then you can render the page based on the `filteredData` array.

All you need to know is the built-in `filter` function of Javascript and the usage of `match` I supose.

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert (started learning recently) but put the onChange function on search bar and try this

```
if(pieceofdata.slug.includes(event.target.value)){
...your code and variables;
return `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> ${symbol}</h1><h1 class= "name"> ${name}</h1><h1 class= "price"> $${price}</h1>
                </div>`;
}
```

it basically compares what you are writing in the search bar and comparing it to the names of "piece of information".

or you could also use filter method for arrays to find the desired element in that array.